# Horizontal scrolling background-image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's my attempt at the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#bg').animate({ backgroundPosition: '320px 0px'}, 10000, 'linear');
});
```

Here's CSS for bg:

```
#bg {
    background: url('scribbles.png') repeat-x 320px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="bg"></div>
```

I want the background image to move across the screen slowly. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the image to continue scrolling forever? If not, the the following may be a good starting point:

`$('#bg').animate({ backgroundPosition: '+=100% 0px'}, 10000, 'linear');`

If it is to repeat forever, then consider the following solution with a recursive call-back:

```
var animateBackground = function()
{
    $('#bg').animate
    (
        { 
            backgroundPosition: '-=100px 0px'
        }, 
        10000,
        'linear',
        function()
        {
            animateBackground(); // recursive call back
        }
    )
};

$( // short-hand for "$(document).ready"
    function()
    {
        animateBackground(); // initial call that starts everything off
    }
);
```

Comment: actually, it scrolls along nicely, but it has moved by background image down the sceen by a hundred pixels or so. Any idea why?

Comment: I forgot that background position works like this:

`background-position: [horizontal] [vertical]`

The answer has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Background position is same for the both css & jquery cases. They should be different. Unless why would it move? Set a previous position in css & give the final position in the jquery part of the code. It'd work!